EF Core manually removing foreign key
What kind of fallout can I expect from manually removing the foreign key constraint generated in EF Core?
We are trying to normalize a table to be used on multiple tables in our system below is a brief example.
Entities:
public class Note
{
    public Guid? MasterId { get; set; }
    public string? MasterType { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public UserValueObject User { get; private set; }
    public string Content { get; private set; }
 
    // Removed for simplicity
}

public class Quote
{
    public Branch Branch { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Note>? Notes { get; private set; } = new List<Note>();

    // Removed for simplicity
}

public class Lead
{
    public DateTime? DateConverted { get; set; }
    public Branch Branch { get; private set; }
    public LeadStatus Status { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Note>? Notes { get; private set; } = new List<Note>();

    // Removed for simplicity
}

EF entity configurations:
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Quote> builder)
{
    // Simplified
    builder.HasMany(x => x.Notes)
           .WithOne()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.MasterId)
           .IsRequired(false)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Lead> builder)
{
    // Simplified
    builder.HasMany(x => x.Notes)
           .WithOne()
           .HasForeignKey(x => x.MasterId)
           .IsRequired(false)
           .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}

The above configurations always generate a foreign key constraint even following the example on (without the navigation property) MS EF Docs
